# Python, User input in the next function

Tags: python

Trying to produce same output with following code.

```
import os
os.system("enum4linx <IP address>")
```

vs

```
import os
HostIP = Host_IP("IP Address of interest :")
os.system("enum4liux <HostIP>")
```

The first script returns me the expected value. But the second one does not. What should I do differently?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? And where does the `Host_IP()` function come from? Are you trying to run the [`enum4linux`](https://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/enum4linux) penetration testing command with with [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are passing your variable within the double quotes, which converts it to a string. Try something like this:

```
IP = "127.0.0.1"

os.system("echo "+IP)  # returns -> 127.0.0.1
```

Hope it helps you